# timestamp Problems PHP

Tags: php

i have this code and i have problem in Datetime() if i get timestamp in my database he working fine but after go to another page and come back to this page code every time the counter come back to 1 seconde and starts counting again

but when use the timestamp directly like this counter work fine

```
$then = new DateTime('2016-03-18 23:47:41' , new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

this code when get timestamp in database
e_time column  give him timestamp type

```
 <?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `e_stauts`=1 AND `lockin`=1 ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $stmt->execute();   
  }
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo"".$row['e_title']." </br>";

    $then = new DateTime(''.$row['e_time'].'' , new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $now = new DateTime();
    $delta = $now->diff($then);

    $quantities = array(
        'year' => $delta->y,
        'month' => $delta->m,
        'day' => $delta->d,
        'hour' => $delta->h,
        'minute' => $delta->i,
        'second' => $delta->s); 

    if($quantities['day'] != 0){
    echo "".$quantities['day']." Day   ".'</br>';   
    }elseif($quantities['day'] == 0 & $quantities['hour'] > 0){
    echo "".$quantities['hour']." Hour  ".'</br>';    
    }elseif($quantities['hour'] == 0 & $quantities['minute'] > 0){
    echo "".$quantities['minute']." Minute   ".'</br>';    
    }elseif($quantities['minute'] == 0 & $quantities['second'] > 0){
    echo "".$quantities['second']." Seconde   ".'</br>';    
    }
     }
```

Comment: How is this timestamp stored in your database ? As an integer, a string, a date type ?

Comment: he stored in timestamp like this 
http://gulf-up.com/do.php?img=74135

Comment: Okay, but what's the type behind that representation ? A string or a datetime format ?

Comment: i don't understand you where can I find type representation ??

Comment: You know that data in SQL database are stored with a certain type right ? Like when you create a table, you have to specify a type for each column of the table. I'm just asking what it is for the column e_time.

Comment: I told you e_time is timestamp type when creat the column i give him  timestamp type